# Purpose of XMLString::transcode

Tags: c++, string, xml-parsing, char, xerces-c

I don't seem to understand the purpose of `XMLString::transcode(XMLCh*)` and `XMLString::transcode(char*)` , because obviously I don't understand the difference between `XMLCh*` and `char*`.
Can someone please make things clearer for me ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Xerces encodes information as UTF-16 internally. The UTF-16 data is stored using the `XMLCh` datatype.

'C-style' strings use `char` which is in the local code page (probably UTF-8, but it depends on the platform and settings) You use `transcode` to convert between the two.

For instance if you want to feed some data from Xerces to another library and that library expects text in the local code page, you need to `transcode` it. Also, if you have `char` data and want to feed it to Xerces, you need to `transcode` it to `XMLCh`, because that is what Xerces understands.

For example:

```
// to local code page
DOMNode *node = ...;
char* temp = XMLString::transcode(node->getNodeValue()); 
std::string value(temp);
XMLString::release(&temp); 

// from local code page
DOMElement *element = ...;
XMLCh *tag = XMLString::transcode("test");
DOMNodeList *list = element->getElementsByTagName(tag);
XMLString::release(&tag);
```

Do not forget to release the string! Better is to write some wrapper round it but there are [examples](http://alfps.wordpress.com/2010/05/27/cppx-xerces-strings-simplified-by-ownership-part-i/) available on the internet (just search for a class named `XercesString`).

If you want to know more about encodings I think you should read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Adding a few lines of code as an example will help a lot to other readers like me!

Answer (score 0):

Kind of nevermind, since I had mistakenly tried transcode on a char* which had been merely cast to XMLCh*. In that case transcode failed but the below code succeeded. As given below, xmlch_abc represents a (XMLCh*)char* . This answer given in case someone else finds themselves in the same unusual situation, program crashing caused by pilot error.

```
TranscodeToStr tts(xmlch_abc,"utf-16");
const unsigned char * chstr = tts.str();

std::cout<<chstr<<std::endl;
```